# Visual Studio 2017 15.5 fp:strict and numeric header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 15.5, including the header `<numeric>` with enabling the options `/fp:strict` and `/std:c++17` generates C3199 error. It seems that some codes in `<numeric>` contain the pragma that causes the error:

```
#pragma float_control(precise, off, push)
...
#pragma float_control(pop)
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It is a bug report for MSFT, [already filed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162020/c3199-including-in-155.html).